# How to verify kotlin varargs function using mockito

Tags: mockito, kotlin

I have a kotlin function of this form in an interface:

```
fun foo(bar: String, vararg baz: Pair<String, ByteArray>):Boolean
```

**Using Mockito to mock this interface, how do I verify that this function was called with no Pairs?**

It doesn't work leaving the second matcher off, because then Mockito complains that it needs two matchers.

Using any `any*()` matcher, including `anyVararg()`, fails because of typing.

Comment: Did you try to use [the spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) with `anyVararg`: `*anyVararg()`?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin for some ideas

Comment: Put up a small edit to my answer. Please let me know if you find something helpful there.

Answer (score 2):

A non-answer to give some inspiration:

Keep in mind that Mockito doesn't know or care what you are writing in some Kotlin source code file.

Mockito only deals with the **compiled** byte code. In other words: Mockito looks into the final classfile; created by the kotlin compiler.

Thus: your first stop should be `javap` to disassemble the class file that contains that method definition. You check the signature of the method **there**; and that should tell you how to specify correct argument matchers to Mockito.

And just another idea: java varargs translate arrays. So "no" args means: an empty array. So you probably want to match specifically on something like `empty array of Pairs`.