# Mockito 4.11.0 vararg changes causes test to fail - how to properly test vararg methods?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I recently made a PR to update to Mockito 4.11.0 but noticed some failing tests related to vararg usage.

Here's a sample that is failing now:

The code that is being tested:

```
package com.xyz.packagexyz

open class TestService {
    fun doSomethingElse(message: String, vararg args: Any) {
        print("message: $message, args: $args")
    }
}

class TestClass(val service: TestService) {
    fun doSomething(message: String, vararg args: Any) {
        service.doSomethingElse(message, args)
    }
}
```

The test code for this is:

```
internal class TestClassTest {
    private val mockService = mock<TestService>()
    private val testClass = TestClass(mockService)

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val message = "message"
        val arg1 = "arg1"
        testClass.doSomething(message, arg1)

        verify(mockService).doSomethingElse(message, arrayOf(arg1))
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
testService.doSomethingElse(
    "message",
    ["arg1"]
);
-> at com.xyz.packagexyz.TestService.doSomethingElse(TestClass.kt:5)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
testService.doSomethingElse(
    "message",
    ["arg1"]
);
-> at com.xyz.packagexyz.TestClass.doSomething(TestClass.kt:11)
```

This code works fine with 4.10.0.

I know 4.11.0 changed a lot of vararg handling logic, so I'm wondering what I need to do to get these to pass now.  Any thoughts?

edit1: I've also tried using

```
verify(mockService).doSomethingElse(message, arg1)
```

which does not include the array wrapping `arg1`, but this fails as well:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
testService.doSomethingElse(
    "message",
    "arg1"
);
-> at com.zao.utilcommon.TestService.doSomethingElse(TestClass.kt:5)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
testService.doSomethingElse(
    "message",
    ["arg1"]
);
-> at com.zao.utilcommon.TestClass.doSomething(TestClass.kt:11)
```

edit2: Thanks in part to [knittl's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75034431/mockito-4-11-0-vararg-changes-causes-test-to-fail-how-to-properly-test-vararg?noredirect=1#comment132416719_75034431) I found two working solutions, but I still don't "like" them and feel the original code should still work...

Option A:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val message = "message"
    val arg1 = "arg1"
    val argsArgCaptor = argumentCaptor<Any>()

    testClass.doSomething(message, arg1)

    verify(mockService).doSomethingElse(eq("message"), argsArgCaptor.capture())

    val argsArray: Array<*>? = argsArgCaptor.firstValue as? Array<*>
    assertEquals(arg1, argsArray?.firstOrNull())
}
```

Option B:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val message = "message"
    val arg1 = "arg1"

    testClass.doSomething(message, arg1)

    verify(mockService).doSomethingElse(eq("message"), argThat {
        val argsArray: Array<*>? = this as? Array<*>

        Arrays.equals(argsArray, arrayOf(arg1))
    })
}
```

edit3: I opened https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2856 for this

Comment: `verify(mockService).doSomethingElse(message, arg1)`?

Comment: I should have mentioned that, right!

This also fails, unfortunately.  The second expected params it's looking for is `["arg1"]` so passing in just `arg1` does not work.

This fails for 4.10.0 and 4.11.0, with the same reason/message.  I will edit my original post to include this though!

Comment: Also, did you try to use `ArgumentMatchers`, e.g. `eq`?

Comment: I will give `ArgumentMatchers` a try - that might work, but also be less "easy" to read/understand.  I'd have to use two in this case, one for `message` and one for `args` value.

What is `eq` though? edit: sorry I was confusing this with `ArgumentCaptor` values.  What do you mean by `ArgumentMatchers`?

Comment: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html

Comment: I see - something like `verify(mockService).doSomethingElse(eq("message"), any())` works, but I can't test the second value to know that "arg1" is passed which IMO is important.

Comment: Can you do `eq(arrayOf(arg1))`? If that does not work, perhaps `argThat(a -> Arrays.equals(a, arrayOf(arg1)))`? Is there anything in the release notes mentioning this? Is it only broken for Kotlin or also for Java code? Perhaps it is a bug after all

Comment: `eq(arrayOf(arg1))` gives the same error message as the original code (which makes sense...).  

I **was** able to get the `argThat` method working.  It's similar to using an argument captor for the second value.  I'll update my post.  I still feel like this is a bug/regression in mockito though...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify kotlin varargs function using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788402/how-to-verify-kotlin-varargs-function-using-mockito)

Comment: Looks like a limitation of Mockito: see release notes of Mockito 5 where var-args are mentioned: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v5.0.0